# I want to pass a integer (user.id) parameter to Cell view in cakephp 3 but I got this

Tags: cakephp, view, cell, cakephp-3.0

I have a cell in Cakephp 3 that I want to show the number of commandes that the logged user has in the Database table 'commandes' . this Cell I want to show it in the default.ctp layout
Here is the code that shows the Cell:

```
    <?php
    // Get the logged user id     
    $iduu=intval($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id')); 
    // here it shows an  integer ( the real user id )
    debug($iduu);  ?>

// I pass it to the Cell to count number of commandes

    <?=  $n = $this->cell('Nbre::display',[$iduu]) ?>
```

//but in the Cell Controller 
//wehen I debug the $idu it shows that is a boolean with value true .

```
class NbreCell extends Cell
{

    /**
     * List of valid options that can be passed into this
     * cell's constructor.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_validCellOptions = [];

    /**
     * Default display method.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function display($idu=0)
    {


        $this->loadModel('Commandes');
        if($idu=!0)
        {
            $n=$this->Commandes->find('all')->where(['Commandes.user_id'=> (int)$idu ])->count();

        }
         debug($idu); // here it shows a boolean TRUE 


        $this->set('n',$n);
        $this->set('idu',$idu);

    }
}
```

Comment: Watch your syntax, `=!` is an assignment, ie you are assigning `$idu` the result of `!0`, which is a boolean. Modern IDEs can prevent such problems, many of them ship with inspections that would mark such an assignment in a condition as a possible problem.

Comment: Thank you a lot . It's working now . You saved my day